# Compute all palindromic substrings of length ≥ 7 of a textfile

Tags: python, list, function, palindrome

Write a program that given a long string (say order 1.000.000 characters), computes all palindromic substrings of length ≥ 7, i.e. substrings spelled identical read forwards and backwards. You can use the below code to read a complete text from a file to a string, convert it to lower case, and remove everything except letters and digits. The file saxo.txt is a local copy of http://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/1150/pg1150.txt

```
from string import ascii_letters, digits

s = open("The Danish History.txt").read()
s = s.lower()
s = "".join([c for c in s if c in ascii_letters or c in digits])

def isPalindrome(str):
    def isPal(str):
        if len(str) >= 7:
            return True
        else:
            str[0] == str[-1] and isPal(str[1:-1])

    return isPal(s)


print(isPalindrome(s))
```

I got this this exercise where I have to compute all palindromic substrings of length ≥ 7 of a textfile. I have used the above codes to show that my string/textfile is a palindrome. I don't know what I have to do now to compute a list of all palindromic substrings of length ≥ 7.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is "a" a palindrome?

Comment: Looks like the problem statement says `compute all palindromic substrings of length ≥ 7 `

Comment: yes, I think so @gilch

Comment: There is no reason to spend more than a single line of code to check if a string is a palindrome. Using a recursive function for that is much too indirect.

Comment: Actually your `isPalindrome` code looks wrong

Comment: Doesn't the code return `True` whenever the length of a word is ≥ 7, even when it is _not_ a palindrome?

Comment: to check if a string is palindrome, you can check `txt = 'hello' ; txt == txt[::-1]`. If True, its a palindrome, if False, not a palindrome. The solution is to go through the full set of 1,000,000 chars to see which parts of the strings are palindromes

Comment: @JohnColeman I am trying, this course is new for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function will return `True` whenever the length of a word is greater or equal to 7, regardless of it being a palindrome. You can check whether the reversed version of a string is the same as the original string: `string[::-1] == string` would suffice.

It seems to me that "palindromic substrings" does not mean palindromic *words*. In that case, you might want to loop over all the *substrings*, not just words split by the whitespaces. There might be more efficient ways to do this, but the following is my suggestion:

```py
from string import ascii_letters, digits

with open('The Danish History.txt', 'r') as f:
    s = f.read()

s = s.lower()
s = "".join([c for c in s if c in ascii_letters or c in digits])

palins = []
for length in range(7, len(s) + 1): # loop over possible lengths
    for start in range(len(s) - length): # loop over starting positions
        substring = s[start:start+length]
        if substring[::-1] == substring: # if palindromic
            palins.append(substring)
```